# Smooth Transition on fieldset using radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I have searched all over the web, but I can't seem to find a solution that suits my needs. I'm fairly new to jquery/javascript, but I think what I'm trying to do is pretty simple.

I have 2 radio buttons that the user can select, based on the selection, additional input fields (contained in a fieldset) are displayed. **This works fine, but I would like to "pretty it up" by making it appear with a smooth transition.**

Currently, this is what I'm doing

HTML:

```
<label for='student_type'>Freshman or Transfer Student</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="student_type" value="freshman" onclick="show_hs();">Freshman
<input type="radio" name="student_type" value="transfer" onclick="show_college();">Transfer Student<br />

<fieldset id="hs_fields" style="display: none;">
<!--MY INPUTS-->
</fieldset>


<fieldset id="college_fields" style="display: none;">
<!--MY INPUTS-->
</fieldset>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
function show_hs()
{
document.getElementById('hs_fields').style.display = 'block';
hide_college();
}
function hide_hs()
{
    document.getElementById('hs_fields').style.display = 'none';
}

function show_college()
{
    document.getElementById('college_fields').style.display = 'block';
    hide_hs();
}
function hide_college()
{
    document.getElementById('college_fields').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

I will be very happy to elaborate on anything that isn't clear.
Your time is much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: "I will be very happy to elaborate on anything that isn't clear." Your question isn't clear. What do you want to happen? Why is this tagged with jQuery when there is none?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Comment: @j08691 I tagged jquery, because I was not sure if jquery is needed for my solution. I have read about the .show() and .hide() functions, but was not sure how to apply it.

Comment: and I just want the fieldset's to appear using a smooth transition. Currently they just appear using no transition.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for something like jQuery UI's effects?
http://jqueryui.com/show/

**Example:**

`$("#hs_fields").show("blind", {}, 500);`

Comment: yes, that is what I'm looking for. how would I put this in my code? can I just replace `document.getElementById('hs_fields').style.display = 'block';`

Comment: Yes, but you need to include both jQuery and jQuery UI libraries: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/